# Fragments Not showing expected Output

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm newbie to Fragments and I'm trying to work on it. Below is my code. For it. when i run my application I don't have any error message but I'm not getting the output

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

}
```

**MyFragments.java**

```
public class MyFragments extends Fragment {

public MyFragments() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_One"
    android:name="com.benchmark.fragmentsdemo.MyFragments"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
    android:name="com.benchmark.fragmentsdemo.MyFragments"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

please anybody help me

Comment: You mean your fragments aren't showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is not correctly implemented.

Try the following layout.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_One"
    android:name="com.benchmark.fragmentsdemo.MyFragments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
    android:name="com.benchmark.fragmentsdemo.MyFragments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Orientation of parent LinearLayout was vertical and you are were making 
widths of fragment 0dp, instead of height

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out this tutorial about Fragments there is a step by step procedure to creating it, So it may be useful to you **[Click here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)** and also check the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)** which is provided by developer.android.